# Show user reputation in tooltip on Documentation review

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Can you (please) add a reputation tooltip of users submitted an edit in the Documentation, the same as you see the reputation when hovering over a user that commented on a post?

[image]
(BTW - This is a **random user** from a random example)

The reason I'm asking is because when I review submissions from low-reputation users, I double check if the content is original or copied from a third party website.

At the moment I need to open the user profile in a new tab in order to see their reputation.

**EDIT**:

As mentioned by @davidism in the comments, if my feture request is approved - There are more sections missing reputation title ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/revisions/231) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript?tab=activity) + "RECENT CONTRIBUTIONS" box ).

Comment: Perhaps more useful would be the badge level in the tag? I don't care if a user has 100k if it's in PHP and they're editing C#...

Comment: though... if they have a silver+ badge their edit won't show up as a pending change anyway. I'd say... you should double check them all anyway, regardless of the user's rep.

Comment: Yes, of course I'm don't want to imply that new users are likely to copy content, but from previous cases that I identified copied content, it was a submission from a users with low-reputation

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Perhaps more useful than that is to just judge the edit based on its content and not on who submits it?

Comment: @Alon, out of curiosity, what is the threshold from which you stop suspecting people from engaging in plagiarism? Because I've seen fairly hi-rep users doing so in the past...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi 1-500 reputation

Comment: I would like this feature, simply because I'm used to it being available. Pretty much every other place where the display name appears without the reputation next to it, the reputation is available in the tooltip instead. It throws me off having it not available.

Comment: @Alon, ah. Definitely the wrong metric, then :)

Comment: @TylerH Even more useful indeed. I was commenting on the proposal, not necessarily the idea behind the proposal. And Kevin B makes a good point that badge level is somewhat irrelevant anyway.

Comment: @AlonEitan I do agree with the feature request but I don't agree at all with the reasoning behind it and I think it's dangerous to continue holding to that line of reasoning as it is demonstrably false. 50k rep users have committed plagiarism and answered awful questions, and 50 rep users have created shining gem answers.

Comment: @TylerH Thank you for your feedback. The only reason I'm checking new users is because I had previous cases when I discovered copied content and it was from new users. I'm just selecting a random line and google it - Nothing more. And I never meant to discredit new users and suggest that they copy things from other websites

Comment: @KevinB I'm not here representing the plagiarism police :) I check new users because they still don't have a high-reputation as an indication that they are familiar with the rules of SO

Comment: Not just in review, but everywhere in Documentation: comments, revision history, requests, etc.

Comment: Just like the user card on this question!